# Can't install package - failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-yzeutv5u/keyring/

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install the googleanalytics package on Colab, which is running perfectly on my local machine. I run the pip command:

```py
!pip install googleanalytics
```

But when I try to install it on Colab I get the following output:

```py
Collecting googleanalytics
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/bc/0e3bbd0944f68c0c59526fad3d46a1c74b14cee58e515199a8477cb82f81/googleanalytics-0.26.0.tar.gz
Collecting oauth2client==1.5.2 (from googleanalytics)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/41/974970101bde842f23031075bea7f6d051ed82b5fd806b6ef9cc7e983c01/oauth2client-1.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting google-api-python-client==1.4.2 (from googleanalytics)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/51/3c0e5004932754b51de2004503355b8b18dc65932fb2052c569a74d7c113/google_api_python_client-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from googleanalytics) (2.5.3)
Collecting addressable>=1.4.2 (from googleanalytics)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/7c/3aadb546b7704938386bed7e5c3022f53ab8556bacc6e655371bf83d3ae8/addressable-1.4.2.tar.gz
Collecting inspect-it>=0.3.2 (from googleanalytics)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/eabdd15262ab4588eb9cf97201628bf7d218c90541a98c450ddcead76781/inspect-it-0.3.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from googleanalytics) (0.15.3)
Collecting keyring==5.3 (from googleanalytics)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/10/ba3c0179f98e0598873bd41312c476aecee41dafac527ab74e68e24927ab/keyring-5.3.zip
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-yzeutv5u/keyring/
```

Any idea on what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: That's not enough information, to my mind. Does running `pip -v install keyring` show more info?

Comment: It seems already installed, as I get the message Requirement already satisfied: keyring in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (19.0.2)